# Cast operator eigenvalue problem as "matrix form"

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=fv-g\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=-fu-g\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial t}=-H_0\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-H_0\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.
$$
Here $u,v$ and $\eta$ are functions of $(x,y,t)$, $f\in\mathbb{R}$ is a parameter, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $H_0$ is a constant.

Consider this as an operator, i.e.

$$L((u,v,\eta)^T):=\begin{pmatrix}fv-g\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial x}\\-fu-g\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial y}\\-H_0\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-H_0\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}$$

and consider the eigenvalue problem
$$
Lz=\lambda z,~~z=(u,v,\eta)^T.
$$

Can we cast this eigenvalue problem in the form?

$z_t=A(x,y,\eta,\lambda)z$?

---

---Example of what I mean:--

For example, if we have the eigenvalue problem $\lambda U=DU_{xx}+cU_x+\partial_UF(Q)U=:LU$ for the linear operator L (isn't it even a Sturm-Liouville operator?), we can cast this as
$$
u_x=A(x,\lambda)u=(\tilde{A}(x)+\lambda B)u,
$$
where
$$
\tilde{A}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\-D^{-1}\partial_UF(Q(x)) & -cD^{-1}\end{pmatrix},~~B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\D^{-1} & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, I am searching something similar to the system given above.

Comment: Are you looking into writing L as a matrix?

Comment: As in the example, I would like to write  the eigenvalue problem  in the form $z_t=A(x,y,\eta,\lambda)z$.

Comment: Does $z_t$ stand for the derivative with respect to $t$? If so, note that by your definition $z_t := Lz$.

Comment: Yes, $z_t$ is the derivative of z w.r.t. t and $z_t=Lz$. But what I am aiming at is a form $z_t=A(x,y,\eta,\lambda)z$ or $z_t=A(\lambda)z$.. Maybe I do not see your point.

Comment: It seems to me that you right now have $z_t = \lambda I z$ where $I$ is the $3$ by $3$ identity matrix. Maybe I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: If you look at the example I gave, then we can now determine the characteristic polynomial of the matrix A and we find the dispersion relation $\lambda(k)$. Another way to get the dispersion relation is to put in the ansatz $e^{\lambda t}e^{ikx}$. - -  Now for my system, the dispersion relation is said to be found by putting the ansatz $e^{i(kx+ly)+\lambda t}\cdot (u_0,v_0,\eta_0)^T$ into the system. And what I am asking is: Can we again alternatively formulate the eigenvalue problem with such a matrix A in order to find the dispersion relation by the char. polynomial of A?

Comment: The example you gave is 1D. Also, I don't see how you get those matrices...  what does $u$ equal there? Indeed from $z_t = \lambda I z$ is solved by $f \exp(\lambda t)$ for the $t$ dependency (with $f$ a function of other parameters). Instead of casting the equation to the time dependent form, solve for the RHS of $Lz$ equal to $Ez$.

Comment: What is E in your last comment?

Comment: The example I gave is the linearization of $U_t=DU_{xx}+F(U)$ in a traveling wave $Q(\xi), \xi:=x-ct$. In the co-moving frame, we have $U_t=DU_{\xi\xi}+cU_{\xi}+F(U)$ and $Q(\xi)$ is an equilibrium of this equation and we linearize in $Q(\xi)$. This gives $u_t=DU_{\xi\xi}+cU_{\xi}+\partial_U F(Q)U=:LU$. Then the eigenvalue problem $LU=\lambda U$ is cast in the given form.